# Custom Observable with wrapped listener ignores SubscribeOn operator

Tags: rx-java

I have the following setup:

A class responsible to update a value that also offers a way to listens for changes to this value, through a callback:

```java
private static class ValueUpdater<T> {
    Listener<T> listener;

    void update(T value) {
      if (listener != null) this.listener.onValueUpdated(value);
    }

    void setListener(Listener<T> listener) {
      this.listener = listener;
    }

    interface Listener<T> {
      void onValueUpdated(T value);
    }
  }
```

A method that wraps the listener used by that class to an `Observable`:

```java
private static <T> Observable<T> createValueObservable(ValueUpdater<T> valueUpdater) {
    return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
      valueUpdater.setListener(value -> {
        System.out.println("Listener: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
          try {
            subscriber.onNext(value);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            subscriber.onError(e);
          }
        }
      });

      subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> valueUpdater.setListener(null)));
    });
  }
```

Which is then called like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ValueUpdater<Integer> valueUpdater = new ValueUpdater<>();

    createValueObservable(valueUpdater)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Next: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    valueUpdater.update(1);
    valueUpdater.update(2);
    valueUpdater.update(3);
  }
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Listener: main
Next: main
Listener: main
Next: main
Listener: main
Next: main
```

I know that happens because `ValueUpdater.update()` is being called on the main thread and that causes the `Observable` to switch threads internally and ultimately ignore the `SubscribeOn()` operator, as explained in [this blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/observables-and-callbacks-and-threading-oh-my).

What are the best alternatives to this scenario, considering I can't modify the `ValueUpdater` class and I want to be able to apply a `Scheduler` to the upstream `Observable`s?

**Edit:** Just to make it a bit more clear, the point of my question is not to understand why this happens. What I'm trying to understand is the best way to design the code around this behavior, preventing the listener callback to run on the main thread.

The output I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
Listener: RxIoScheduler-3
Next: RxIoScheduler-3
Listener: RxIoScheduler-3
Next: RxIoScheduler-3
Listener: RxIoScheduler-3
Next: RxIoScheduler-3
```

`.observeOn()` is not going to do that, because it only affects items going downstream. If I would apply it, the output would be something like the following:

```
Listener: main
Listener: main
Listener: main
Next: RxIoScheduler-3
Next: RxIoScheduler-3
Next: RxIoScheduler-3
```

I've tried to use `Observable.fromAsync()` like below but it did not work either:

```java
private static <T> Observable<T> createValueObservable(ValueUpdater<T> valueUpdater) {
    return Observable.fromAsync(emitter -> {
      final CompositeSubscription cs = new CompositeSubscription();
      final Scheduler.Worker worker = Schedulers.io().createWorker();
      final ValueUpdater.Listener<T> listener = new ValueUpdater.Listener<T>() {
        @Override public void onValueUpdated(T value) {
          System.out.println("Listener: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          try {
            emitter.onNext(value);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            emitter.onError(e);
          }
        }
      };

      valueUpdater.setListener(listener);

      cs.add(worker);
      cs.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> valueUpdater.setListener(null)));

      emitter.setSubscription(cs);
    }, AsyncEmitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
  }
```

The only possible solution I can think of right now, is to always call `ValueUpdater.update()` from a different thread, but I'm pretty sure that's not practical for a real use case:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ValueUpdater<Integer> valueUpdater = new ValueUpdater<>();

    createValueObservable1(valueUpdater)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Next: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

    Completable.fromAction(() -> {
      valueUpdater.update(1);
      valueUpdater.update(2);
      valueUpdater.update(3);
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe();

    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`.subscribeOn()` only modifies where the subscription `.subscribe(...)` happens (I don't think that it's necessary in your case, as you don't have io/computation in your subscription).

You should also use `.observeOn()` to modify where processing of the items happen.

Edit: No matter how you dice it, the body of the `valueUpdater.update()` will run in the same thread as the caller. However, as you're immediately switching to Rx, this might be what you're looking for:

```
private static <T> Observable<T> createValueObservable(ValueUpdater<T> valueUpdater) {
  return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
    valueUpdater.setListener(value -> {
      if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
        try {
          subscriber.onNext(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          subscriber.onError(e);
        }
      }
    });

    subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> valueUpdater.setListener(null)));
  })
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .doOnNext(any -> System.out.println("Listener: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
}
```

Comment: If you're saying that .subscribeOn() only modifies the code that goes inside the Observable's .subscribe() method, then I don't think that's correct. As for the case above, it is just a minimal example to give the question some context, it shouldn't be viewed as a real case.

Comment: The point that I was (unsuccessfully) to make is that you're calling `valueUpdater.update(1)` from the main thread; if you don't explicitly switch threads, that's what the subscriber will run on. Also, I don't thing you need the `Thread.sleep()` in there.

Comment: Oh, I get what you're saying now, you're right. I do understand that calling `valueUpdater.update‌​‌​(1)` from the main thread causes the subscriber to run on that thread, but the point of my question is that I want to know some good alternatives to handle this situation. Calling `.observeOn()` will only affect the items going downstream, meaning that even if I call it right after `createValueObservab‌​le()`, everything inside the listener's callback will still run inside the main thread, which is not the outcome I want. I'm going to edit the question to make that a bit more clear, thank you!

Comment: Thing is, as I read your edit, that there are no upstream Observables; your source is the method `createValueObservable`; just make it return its value after applying `observeOn`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. How would you do that?